# Android emulator in Visual Studio 2019 : where is /storage/emulated/0 located on dev pc?

Tags: windows-10, android, emulator, visual-studio-2019

The emulator is launching effectively my app from Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 Pro, but where is it storing locations such as Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory (/storage/emulated/0 on mobile) for example, from which my app is supposed to load file contents by the way ?

Via Android Device Manager, from Visual Studio, the location opened in the Explorer for this emulated device displays 4 directories (data, hardware-qemu.ini.lock, snapshots, tmpAdbCmds) and 18 files among which userdata-qemu.img and sdcard.img turn out to be empty once mounted, and a userdata.img file unmountable both on Windows 10 and Ubuntu...

So is there a way to access the emulated file system from the dev pc after all ?

Comment: The location of [/storage/emulated/0/](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205430/) appears to be well documented.  Why are you looking for the physical folder?  You are running Android applications due to the Android Emulator you have installed. To answer your question directly, it appears that `/mnt/shell/emulated/0/`, is the full path to the folder. You should also know that `Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory` is [depreciated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.os.environment.externalstoragedirectory?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12) in Android SDK 12.

Comment: @Ramhound I know it's deprecated, I still need a way to access any simulated storage folder (whether the /data/media/0/ root, or the Downloads folder for example) directly from within my Windows 10 OS before running the app on the emulator in debugging mode, since my app cannot run without loading some files located directly on the device and previously copied on it manually. As long as I can't feed the emulated device with these files, I just can't debug my app using the Android emulator...

Comment: and it would be weird to be able to emulate a virtual Android OS without getting access to its filesystem from the Windows host anyway...

Comment: @ting12 You have access to the Android file-system just like in any Android device using `adb`. You can push/pull files or start the shell. When I check the Android emulator files in my home directory `.android\avd\<emulator name>` the newest file is `userdata-qemu.img.qcow2`. This file should contain the user data partition you are searching for.